# Github Actions - Как ввести данные в файл из Python скрипта в .TXT файл?

Tags: python, github, github-actions

я не особо понимаю, что делать в Github Actions, поэтому спрашиваю, как сделать здесь. В общем, у меня есть такой "Прокси Список", который берет с источников. По идее, он должно ввести данные из скрипта *(response.text)*, а затем писать в `proxy.txt`. Вот код на Python, а также Github Actions:

```
import requests

def scrapeProxy():
    links = []
    with open("proxy_sources.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            links.append(line.strip())

    lamount = len(links)
    print(f"[ ! ] Successfully loaded {lamount} links with HTTP/HTTP's proxy.")

    with open("proxy.txt", "w") as file:
        amount = 0
        for link in links:
            response = requests.get(link)
            if not response.ok:
                print(f"[ - ] {link} returned {response.status_code}. Please check if this link is correct.")
            else:
                file.write(response.text + "\n")

                lines = len(response.text.split('\n'))
                amount += lines
                print(f"[ + ] {lines} lines appeared in proxy.txt")

    print(f"[ ! ] Finished with {amount} proxies from {lamount} in proxy.txt!")

scrapeProxy()
```

```
name: Half-hourly Proxy Scraping

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/30 * * * *"

jobs:
  scrape_proxies:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.x

      - name: Install requests module
        run: pip install requests

      - name: Run scrapeProxy.py
        run: python scrapeProxy.py

      - name: Set Git user
        run: |
          git config user.email "bruh.boy0@yandex.ru"
          git config user.name "bruhb0y"

      - name: Update proxy.txt commit message
        run: |
          echo "новое содержимое" > proxy.txt
          git add proxy.txt
          git commit -m "hi chat"
          git push
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У github action по умолчанию нет прав на запись в репозиторий. Нужно добавить `permission: contents: write`. Для коммита имеет смысл использовать action [`EndBug/add-and-commit`](https://github.com/EndBug/add-and-commit).

На вашем примере будет что-то такое:

```yaml
name: Half-hourly Proxy Scraping

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "*/30 * * * *"

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  scrape_proxies:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.x

      - name: Install requests module
        run: pip install requests

      - name: Run scrapeProxy.py
        run: python scrapeProxy.py

      - name: Commit proxy.txt
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v9.1.3
        with:
          author_name: bruhb0y
          author_email: bruh.boy0@yandex.ru
          add: proxy.txt
          message: hi chat
```